# Convert List to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following problem:

```
public class AwesomeClass
{
    public string SomethingCool { get; set; }
    public string SomethingUseless { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class which contains a number of properties, and I need to convert a list of these classes into a list of strings, where the string represents a property in the class.

```
List<AwesomeClass> stuff = new List<AwesomeClass>();

//Fill the stuff list with some tings.

List<string> theCoolStuff = //Get only the SomethingCool property in the AwesomeClass list.
```

The reason why I need to convert this to a list of strings is because I have a method which takes a List as a parameter, but the SomethingCool property contains the data that I need for this list.

*Note: I could use a **foreach** loop on the list and populate the List of strings but I'm looking for a more elegant method, perhaps LINQ can do this for me?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use `Select`:

```
var theCoolStuff = stuff.Select(x => x.SomethingCool).ToList();
```

What `Select` does is a *projection*, it projects each item and transforms (not convert) them into another form.

Comment: Worth adding that this is in fact a *projection* (or mapping) and not a *conversion* operation.

Comment: @MikeEason - You can appreciate the answer by accepting it.

Comment: @RahulSingh I had to wait a few minutes before I could accept the answer. It's done now.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can even:

```
List<string> theCoolStuff = stuff.ConvertAll(x => x.SomethingCool);
```

because the `List<T>` has a special "conversion" method :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (AwesomeClass member in stuff)
{
   theCoolStuff.Add(member. SomethingCool)
}
```